# Moore neighborhood on a two-dimensional Cartesian lattice

Tags: combinatorics, logic, cellular-automata

How many distinct cellular automata rules are there that use the Moore
neighborhood on a two-dimensional Cartesian lattice if we allow three bits (eight states) per site?

Comment: If you wish to ask a similar question changing the lattice to three dimensions and two bits per site, append the question or ask a new question. Please don't alter the question so that the existing answers make no sense.

Comment: Please do not deface the question. It orphans the answers that people have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule is a function from the input space (here of size $8^8$) to the output space (which is of size $8$). There's $(8^8)^8 = 2^{24 \cdot 8} = 2^{192}$ such functions.

Comment: Would symmetry considerations reduce the number of unique rules?